# Confusing non-numeric argument to binary operator error

Tags: r, function

I cannot seem to even create a reproducible example on this as it works fine when I go through the code one line at a time.

The error message I get is as follows:

> "Error in testData[, colCheck][length(testData[, colCheck])] - testData[,  :
> non-numeric argument to binary operator "

Both `colCheck` and `testData$linearcorrd15N` are numeric and like I said, the calculation works fine when I run it at that line.  The error comes only when I run the function from `QTest(df, colCheck)`.

Here is an example of what some of the code looks like. It will not produce an error, but maybe you can see something that I don't.

```
QTest <- function(testData, colCheck)
  #%#
  # testData <- This is the entire data frame for the std/ref that has too high 
  #             of a SD, this way the data frame can be returned without the outlier
  # colCheck <- The column name for values that were flagged for having too high of a SD
  # This Q test info provided by: https://www.statisticshowto.com/dixons-q-test/
  #%#
{
  #Get the mean of the highest and lowest values
  testData <- arrange(testData, desc(testData[, colCheck]))
  len <- length(testData[,colCheck])-1
  high <- sapply(1:len, function(i) testData[,colCheck][i])
  meanhigh <- mean(high)
  
  testData <- arrange(testData, (testData[, colCheck]))
  low <- sapply(1:len, function(i) testData[,colCheck][i])
  meanlow <- mean(low)
  
  #If the mean of the lowest numbers is lower than the mean of the highest numbers, do this
  if(meanlow < meanhigh){
    QexpVal <- abs((testData[, colCheck][2] - testData[, colCheck][1])/ 
                     (testData[, colCheck][length(testData[, colCheck])] - testData[, colCheck][1]))
    outlier <- testData[,colCheck][1]
    closest <- testData[,colCheck][2]
    #else if the mean of the lowest numbers is higher than the mean of the highest numbers, do this
  } else {
    QexpVal <- abs((testData[, colCheck][length(testData[,colCheck])-1] - (testData[, colCheck][length(testData[,colCheck])])) /
                     (testData[,colCheck][length(testData[,colCheck])]) - (testData[,colCheck][1]))
    outlier <- testData[,colCheck][length(testData[,colCheck])]
    closest <- testData[,colCheck][length(testData[,colCheck])-1]
  }
  return(QexpVal)
}

df <- data.frame(Row = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Identifier.2 = "36-UWSIF-UT Glut1", linearcorrd15N = c(-11.63433, 
                 -22.13869, -57.21795, -17.06438, -16.23358))

colCheck <- as.numeric(grep("linearcorrd15N", colnames(std1)))

QTestCorrVals <- QTest(df, colCheck)
```

Comment: A few ideas: `tail` is a nice way to get the last element of a vector. So instead of `testData[, colCheck][length(testData[, colCheck])]` you could use `tail(testData[, colCheck], 1)`.

Comment: I *think* you're using a bit of `dplyr`? I see `arrange()` in there, but nothing else. If `colCheck` is a string column name, I'd suggest changing `arrange(testData, (testData[, colCheck]))` to `testData[order(testData[, colCheck]), ]`

Comment: With `len` being the number of rows in the data minus 1, there will likely be issues with `sapply(1:len, function(i) testData[,colCheck][i])` if the input data has 1 row, because then `1:len` will be `1:0`.

Comment: If you are are extracting a single column every time you use `testData[,colCheck]`, I would suggest using `testData[[colCheck]]` to be safer, making it very clear that you will get a vector result, not a data frame.

Comment: Extending the `tail` comment above, `tail(x, 2)` gives the last 2 elements of `x`. So if you want the difference between the last 2 elements, `diff(tail(x, 2))` is nice and concise.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for all this info.  I like the tail idea.  colCheck is a number.  3 in the case of this example and when I changed it to [[colCheck]] it threw an error.  The data will never be of length 1 so the sapply function should be ok.

Comment: @GregorThomas ignoring all else, do you have any idea why I'm getting this error when applying the function?  Everything in the function works fine when I run it line by line.

Comment: If you can help me reproduce the error, I can give it a go. The mix of `dplyr` and base can cause problems, hence my advice to use `[[`. Not being able to debug it myself, that's the first thing I would change. But there's a lot of simplification possible, I think Merijn's answer is a nice start.

Comment: Are you using any of the columns other than `colcheck`? It doesn't look it... In which   case you should probably write a function that takes a vector as input, not a whole data frame. It will be much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

It seems you realy overcomplicate this function by pushing the whole table in the function and loop over everything and read a value again from the whole table...

just the part to get meanhigh and meanlow requires this:

```
v <- df[, colCheck]
v <- v[order(v)]
n <- length(v)

meanhigh <- mean(v[2:n])
meanlow  <- mean(v[1:n-1])
```

Or if you use the decreasing ordering this:

```
v <- df[, colCheck]
v <- v[order(v, decreasing = T)]
n <- length(v)

meanhigh <- mean(v[1:n-1])
meanlow  <- mean(v[2:n])
```

**Full function**

Hereby the full code using this approach and I agree that is not the specific question you asked, but the way you coded it is highly inefficient and error prone by every time take the whole data.frame and subset it and recalculate lengths every time. Also you just have to order once, as if the lowest is on top, the highest is per definition on the bottom. Then play around with the 1 for first and 2 for second and n for last and n-1 for second last.

```
df <- data.frame(Row = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Identifier.2 = "36-UWSIF-UT Glut1", linearcorrd15N = c(-11.63433, 
                 -22.13869, -57.21795, -17.06438, -16.23358))
colCheck <- as.numeric(grep("linearcorrd15N", colnames(df)))

QTest <- function(v) {
  v <- v[order(v)]
  n <- length(v)
  meanhigh <- mean(v[2:n])
  meanlow  <- mean(v[1:n-1])
  if(meanlow < meanhigh) {
    QexpVal <- abs((v[2]-v[1])/(v[n]-v[1]))
    outlier <- v[1]
    closest <- v[2]
  } else {
    QexpVal <- abs((v[n-1]-v[n])/(v[n]-v[1]))
    outlier <- v[n]
    closest <- v[n-1]
  }
  return(QexpVal)
}

QTestCorrVals <- QTest(df[, colCheck])
```

**Side note**

Using the column index number works slightly different whether your data is a data.frame or a data.table

```
class(df)
df[, colCheck]
dt <- data.table(df)
class(dt)
dt[, ..colCheck]
dt[, colCheck] # throws an error
```

Comment: You are probably right, but this does not address my question.  I appreciate you trying to help me improve my code.  I am pretty new to R.

Comment: I updated my post with the full function, I understand it does not address your direct question, but your inexperience resulted in an inefficient approach and is very error prone.

Comment: THANK YOU!  This completely solved my problem.  And thank you for showing me a more efficient way of doing this.  I tend to make things harder than they need to be when writing code.